# Issues with restarting tomcat via cron

Tags: tomcat, server, cron

I  am trying to restart server everyday. So i added restart script as cron job. But when the script runs, it is not restarting properly, providing

> Address 8080 is already in use exception

```
sh /TomcatLocation/bin/shutdown.sh
sleep 30
sh /TomcatLocation/bin/startup.sh
```

This is the code I have added in the script. But if i run the script separately, it is starting without any trouble.

Comment: Maybe another Apache Tomcat instance is running. You can use this solution: edit the root crontab, by doing `sudo crontab -e`, and enter the line: `0 0 */1 * * /usr/bin/service tomcat7 restart`  It means restart Tomcat per day at 00:00

Comment: But i am doing the same already!! it starts some days, some days it fails.. very inconsistent

Comment: Especially if it's inconsistent: What other help do you expect than "another application - most likely tomcat - is blocking the port"? When this happens: Investigate if shutting down fails or just takes longer than expected. But, more importantly: There's no reason within tomcat to restart every day. If there is one in your custom application deployed on tomcat, you might rather want to fix that, rather than investing effort into such a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because `shutdown.sh` sometimes doesn't shutdown Tomcat properly. To be sure that Tomcat was closed you could kill process listening to a specific port. You should be aware that if Tomcat was off before running the script then the script will encounter exception on the line `.../shutdown.sh` and this sometimes stops the script.

```
./shutdown.sh && echo "Tomcat was already shutdown"
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN)
./startup.sh
```